# How can I implement MongoDB autocomplete in Golang using mongo driver?

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to implement a [autocomplete search](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/autocomplete/) in golang but I keep getting an error with the syntax

```
contactsCollection := c.DB.Database("XYZ").Collection("contacts")

    result, err := contactsCollection.aggregate([{
            "$search": {
                "autocomplete": {
                    "query": searchQuery,
                    "path": "email",
                    "tokenOrder": "any"
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

`searchQuery` is the input coming in and email is the field upon which I want to do the autocomplete. I am assuming that I would be able to return `result`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out some [tutorials](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-golang-mongodb-starting-and-setup) or docs on how to use the MongoDB client in Go. You will need to use the [bson](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson?utm_source=godoc) package to write queries.

```
cursor, err := contactsCollection.Aggregate(ctx, bson.A{
    bson.M{"$search": bson.M{"autocomplete": bson.M{
        "query":      searchQuery,
        "path":       "email",
        "tokenOrder": "any",
    }}},
})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
var results []MyDocument
err = cursor.All(ctx, &results)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```